# css-grid sass -> css not behaving

Tags: css, css-grid

So for some reason, this sass code won't compile I have no clue why atm. I've gone code blind so I need help.
There is something happening between the end of the areas and the first parts.

Here the sass. 
html, body
    margin: 0
    padding: 0

## maincontainer

```
display: grid
width: 100vw
height: 100vh
grid-gap: 5px
grid-template-columns: 0.5fr 1fr 1fr 0.5fr
grid-template-rows: 100px 2fr 4fr 6fr 100px
grid-template-areas: ". toplogo topnav ." ". mainlogo mainsearch ." "jumboimage jumboimage jumboimage jumboimage" ". mainnews mainscehdule ." "footer footer footer footer";


.toplogo:
    grid-area: toplogo

.topnav:
    grid-area: topnav

.mainlogo:
    grid-area: mainlogo

.mainsearch
    grid-area: mainsearch

.jumboimage
    grid-area: jumboimage
    background-image: url("../images/jumbo.png")
    background-size: cover

.mainnews
    grid-area: mainnews

.mainscehdule
    grid-area: mainscehdule

.footer
    grid-area: footer
```

Comment: You have a semi-colon at the end of your `grid-template-areas` property. Is that it

Comment: Sorry that was there for error searching, since that is the error I get. in SASS that should not be there.